# Why can't I insert to table in SP invoked by trigger on same table?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I create table called student which contain trigger. I want to insert data through SP to this table. When I execute SP (or normal way of insert record to table) it gives me below error.
**" Can't update table 'student' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."**

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crd`.`student` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `age` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `stuCode` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 45
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
```

And my trigger is:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger genCode BEFORE INSERT on student for each row
BEGIN
INSERT INTO student SET student.age = 12;
END$$
```

And SP is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetDetails`(IN `gage` INT, IN `gname` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO student (name,age) VALUES (gname,gage);
select name from student where id=LAST_INSERT_id();
END
```

Please help to solve this problem.

I change my trigger to add number to student table stuCode column:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger genCode AFTER INSERT on student for each row

BEGIN
declare refno varchar(10);
declare refnonew varchar(10);
select refno=student.stuCode into refno FROM student where student.id=(select MAX(student.id) from student);
if (refno is null) or (refno='') then
    set refnonew='000000001';
    UPDATE student
       SET student.stuCode = refnonew where student.id=LAST_INSERT_id();
end if;
END$$
```

It gives the same error?/ Why??

Comment: The error message already says it: You shouldn't modify the table in a trigger that fired when modifying the table. In this case you try to insert an extra student every time when someone inserts a student...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message already says it: You shouldn't modify the table in a trigger that fired when modifying the table. In this case you try to insert an extra student every time when someone inserts a student...

It looks like intend to set just the age of the new student. To do that you can use the `new` variable, which points to the record being inserted:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger genCode BEFORE INSERT on student for each row
BEGIN
  NEW.age = 12;
END$$
```

See [MySQL trigger syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Or you could simply set a default value for the column:

```
ALTER TABLE student MODIFY COLUMN age INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 12;
```

See [MySQL alter table syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

In my opinion it's best not to do this though. Not every student is 12 when they enter, and triggers should be used for enforcing only the most important business logic. I know from a decade of experience that triggers like this make maintenance hard in the future, because at some point you want to remove this default, and code will break in unexpected places.

If you want a feature like this, it's better to declare a default age (of 12), and prefill this in your UI.